# Split the Row into multiple rows in SQL using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in the following format in table.

```
ORDER_ID   PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY
O1          A1           3
```

I need to write the sql query to divide the data into following format:

```
ORDER_ID   PRODUCT_ID   QUANTITY
O1          A1           1
O1          A1           1
O1          A1           1
```

Query should split the data based on the Value in quantity column.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
SELECT
  ORDER_ID, 
  PRODUCT_ID, 
  1 QUANTITY 
from 
  dual LEFT JOIN YourTable T on 1=1
connect by level <= T.Quantity
```